# Getting error while opening form in visual studio 2005

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

i am getting below excetion on opening a form on visual studio work bench 
Its not always but sometime it opens without any problem
Does anyone has a solution for this?

The path is not of a legal form. 
Hide

```
at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AddProjectDependencies(Project project)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ReferenceType refType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetType(ITypeResolutionService trs, String name, Dictionary`2 names)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.FillStatementTable(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, IDictionary table, Dictionary`2 names, CodeStatementCollection statements, String className)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Comment: As the message says; a path is invalid.

Is there a path mentioned in the message? As far as I can see in the stacktrace something is wrong with the project dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

From [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/111082/the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form):

> This is a known issue and is a
>   regression from VS 2003. If this is
>   the known issue, this error happens
>   because a reference cannot be resolved
>   in your project. When the designer
>   loads, it attempts to locate and load
>   every assembly that is in your
>   reference list. In C#, you can expand
>   the reference list to see this. In VB,
>   you must click the "Show All Files"
>   button in the solution explorer window
>   to view the references collection. Try
>   to remove dead references, or remove
>   and re-add any custom references and
>   then reload the designer.

I would also clean your solution and rebuild (right click your solution in VS and select Clean, right click again and select Rebuild).

Answer (score 0):

Install resharper. In VS right click on references and choose 'optimize references' , after clean+rebuild probably no problem exists!